# Why do I get a wrong number of arguments error on an advanced query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to filter my posts but get a wrong number of arguments error (given 1, expected 0)

Im trying to filter them based off of the condition

```
if current_user.courses.any? {|h| h[:name] == post.course.name}
```

Here is my controller action for index

```
def index
@posts = Post.all(:joins => :course, :conditions => "courses.name in (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).join(',')})",:order => "posts.created_at DESC")
end
```

Here are my models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course
has_many :comments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
belongs_to :major
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :courses
belongs_to :major
has_many :posts
has_many :comments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses, reject_if: :all_blank,     allow_destroy: true
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there are (at least) two `any?` methods. First is the `Enumerable` [any?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F), which is what you are wanting it seems. However, it looks like the one that actually runs is the `ActiveRecord` [any?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/any%3F). The first iterates through the block you provide and returns if at least one returns true. The second one doesn't take any arguments and lets you know if there are any records that exist.

With what you are wanting, I would change your code to:

```
#This converts courses to an array
if current_user.courses.to_a.any? {|h| h[:name] == post.course.name}
```

OR

```
#This uses the method select instead
if current_user.courses.select{|h| h[:name] == post.course.name}.count > 0
```